# Table where global names is stored

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, table

I have an issue in Magento where few of my tables and reports are showing the product `names/Category` in French language.We do have a store at France and in other countries, but the requirement is to show the global values of `category/Product` names in the reports.

So can anyone help to find in which table in Magento is storing the global `category/ names of products`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add propper (version) tags?

Comment: @sv3n Added proper version.Do you have any idea on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product name in Magento is considered as product attribute.

So you need to search the same in eav_attribute table.

When you run this query:

```
select * from eav_attribute where frontend_label="Product Name";
```

you will get an attribute_id associated for product name.

Now using this id find the product name in catalog_product_entity_varchar where all the attribute values are stored.

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id= <product_name_attribute_id>;
```

It will list down all the product names based on store_id.
Note: The listing will be for product's row_id not entity_id.

All the best

Comment: will check on it and will update you.

Comment: In certain tables the category names and other values are in french versions,Do you have any idea where i need to correct those to get the global names in the backed(The front end is showing correctly) in backend its saving as French ones(only for certain orders), i need to rectify it or update the backend with global values.